# How can I send data between Intel Edison and a mobile device using Ad Hoc or SoftAP?

Tags: wifi, intel, adhoc, access-point, intel-edison

I am working on a project where I need to transfer data between an Intel Edison and a mobile device (hoping for cross platform compatability) without using a router. I have considered Wi-Fi Direct, but this is not available on iOS and only available on a handful of android devices. Furthermore, in the Intel Edison Wi-Fi guide (link below), it tells you how to use ad hoc mode, but only between two Intel Edison devices. I am also not sure whether Android devices can connect to an ad hoc network. 
So my question is whether or not using the Intel Edison's SoftAP mode will allow me to transfer data to and from an Intel edison and a mobile device? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Intel edison wifi guide:
http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edison_wifi_331438001.pdf

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Wifi, SoftAP seems like to be the best option. But if you need a short range connection, you should consider Bluetooth. Since nowadays there are lots of wifi APs around us, the user might be forced to disconnect from his internet-accessing wifi AP to connect to your data network which might be inconvenient for him/her.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Using Bluetooth was my first choice, but I want to connect multiple devices to the Intel Edison without initiating the connection on the Edison side. From my understanding, due to the master/slave architecture of Bluetooth the master has to initiate the connection meaning the mobile device would have to be the master and that would only only allow one device connected to the Intel Edison at a time :( Would really appreciate it if you have anymore insight. Thanks!